# To convert (or not to convert) ASP.NET to Php

Tags: php, asp.net

need some advice here.

I stumble upon 1 useful set o codes from this [site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CrossDomainSSOExample.aspx)

It is written in ASP.NET. I want to make use of the SSOLib (library, but C# codes provided) from the ASP.NET to be used in Php.

Should I rewrite all the C# codes into Php codes/files?

Or should I look for another way to get the functionality from the SSOLib library and port it to Php.

What would be the pros and cons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide the C# code in a webservice that is consumed by your php site